# Run Geoserver on Port 80

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I have geoserver installation that is accessable on both, port 80 and port 8080.

Now, I try to install another instance of geoserver on a different server.

I can access it on port 8080, but not on port 80. I could not find out where to flip the switch to make it run on port 80 as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence "I have geoserver installation that is accessable on both, port 80 and port 8080." please, clarify.

Indicate also which OS you are running onto, which version of GeoServer and which packaging you used (cross platform bin, exe, war with tomcat, etc..)

Comment: Red Hat Linux release 4,
Geoserver 2.4.4, war with tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Ferenjito,
I would not expose both port 8080 and 80 and above all I would not make Tomcat work on port 80.

My best suggestion is to have something like apache httpd in front of tomcat and have the two talk to each via AJP leaving port 80 in the hands of httpd.
Basic/startup docs [here](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/load_balancing/apache_http.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is exactly how I did it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not advised to have a server listening on multiple ports. The port settings for Geoserver, running under Tomcat, are set in the `server.xml` file, which in my setup, is located under `/etc/tomcat6/server.xml`. Open this, find the connector port, change to 80, restart tomcat, eg,

```
<Service name="Catalina">
   <Connector port="80" ....
```

As the port is set under Tomcat, not Geoserver, if you want to run two instances of Geoserver on the same machine, you will need to set up two version of Tomcat, one listening on 80 and the other on 8080, and then deploy your Geoserver.war file into each one separately.